# Read ~/.aws/credentials file on osx using dotnet

Tags: c#, .net, macos, amazon-web-services

Excerpt from `Startup.cs`

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddOptions();

    var awsConfig = Configuration.GetAWSOptions();
    //awsConfig.ProfilesLocation = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(awsConfig.ProfilesLocation);
    services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(awsConfig);

    services.AddAWSService<IAmazonElasticLoadBalancing>();
    services.AddAWSService<IAmazonCloudWatch>();
}
```

Excerpt from `appsettings.json`

```
{
  "AWS": {
    "Profile": "prod",
    "Region": "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

The code above builds fine but when I run it, it cannot find my profiles in my `~/.aws/credentials` file. If I set my environment variables

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
```

Then it runs correctly.

If this is run on windows without the environment variables set, it will find the credentials file correctly.

Any idea how to set this up so it works on both Windows and OSX?

References:

- [AWS SDK .NET Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-netcore.html)
- [.NET Core and AWSSDK on Mac, credentials file not found](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=754622)

Comment: I wonder if you found a solution for this, I'm also blocked by this on mac :(

Comment: Same here. Any tips?